# Hyphens within decades

Tags: hyphenation

Should there be a hyphen in the sentence, early '80s or should it be written without the hyphen between early and '80s?

Comment: The answer is Yes and No, depending on how "early 80s" is used. Could you give a couple of examples?

Comment: Every decade is different on the general usage of hyphens. the 1960's used them -all- the time, the 1990's hardly ever. It's a fashion pendulum.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using *80s* as a noun, it should not have a hyphen, because we don't normally join adjectives (*early*) to nouns (*80s*) with hyphens:

- *He wrote that song in the early 80s.*

If you're using *early 80s* as a compound adjective, a hyphen is optional, and (depending on context) can add clarity:

- *That's an early-80s song.*

Answer (score 0):

It should be like early 80's and I don't think any hyphen is needed.

-edited

Comment: "Early" does not need a capital letter in mid-sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I think when it's used as an adjective, you use a hyphen: "That song you just wrote sounds so early-80s." I've been taught to do that when I want a phrase to serve as an adjective. I see it done in a lot of writing.

Side note: About the placement or omission of the apostrophe - I'm not sure.

Comment: It is not a possessive, so it doesn't need an apostrophe (although there was a tendency to include them when putting a plural "s" after digits).

Comment: If you are talking about the apostrophe before the plural s, it should not be there. If you are talking about the apostrophe before the 8, it should be there, at least according to the CMS.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What's "the CMS"

Comment: @TrevorD, the Chicago Manual of Style (the only one I had quick online access to). Forgive me if that is not on the list of common reference abbreviations—I assumed it was without checking.